# Why do I keep seeing the undefined index error for line 13 ('file')?

Tags: indexing

I am trying to create a simple drag and drop page using php. When I click the "submit" button, I get an error: Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\DragAndDrop\includes\gallery-upload.inc.php on line 13. Why is it not reading the "file" index from the htmlphp?

Here is the HTML and PHP code:

```
enter code here
 <!--continuted from HTML page-->
    </section>
<?php
  $_SESSION['username'] = "Admin";
  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  echo '<div class="gallery-upload">
  <form action="includes/gallery-upload.inc.php" method="post" enctype="mutipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="File Name...">
    <input type="text" name="filetitle" placeholder="Image Title...">
    <input type="text" name="filedesc" placeholder="Image description...">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
    </div>';
      }
  ?>
</main>
</body>
</html>

<!--and the php page-->
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {//checks submit form and posts the info

    $newFileName = $_POST['filename'];
    if (empty($_POST['filename'])) { //if filename is emptly
        $newFileName = "gallery"; //if filename is empty, generates name
          } else {
              $newFileName = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $newFileName));  //if spaces are in the name, creates stringholder
            }
          $imageTitle = $_POST['filetitle'];
          $imageDesc = $_POST['filedesc'];
          $file = $_FILES['file'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
mutipart/form-data
```

Should be

```
multipart/form-data
```

Comment: D'oh! Thanks very much...it was driving me crazy!